# Saving Dictionary of custom NSCoding objects to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, nsuserdefaults

I have a custom object which implements NSCoding, it looks like this (simplified of course):

```
@implementation FooBarThing

    @synthesize foo = _foo;
    @synthesize bar = _bar;

    - (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _foo = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:FOO] retain];
            _bar = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:BAR] retain];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
    {
        [coder encodeObject:self.foo forKey:FOO];
        [coder encodeObject:self.bar forKey:BAR];
    }
@end
```

Currently I save an array of my custom class to  NSUserDefaults like so:

```
-(void)saveResults:(NSArray *)results
{
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:results];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"RESULTS"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(NSArray*)readResults
{
    NSData *results = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"RESULTS"];
    NSArray *resultsArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:results];
    return resultsArray;
}
```

What I want to do, is store the array of results in a dictionary, keyed by a string like so:

```
-(void)saveResults:(NSArray *)scanResults  forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    ???
}

-(NSArray*)readResults:(NSString *) key
{
    ???
}
```

Having troulbe getting the syntax correct, Im starting to believe Im just over thinking this, so help would be apprecaited!
Thanks!

--

Edit:

I've since solved this, it was quite simple just had a momentary lapse.  Perhaps not the best option, so open to any suggestions to improve!

```
-(void)saveResults:(NSArray *)results forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self getResultsDict]];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:results];
    if(dict == nil){
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:data forKey:key];
    }else{
        [dict setObject:data forKey:key];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:dict forKey:@"RESULTS_DICT"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}

-(NSArray*)readFullResults:(NSString *)key
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self getResultsDict];
    NSArray *result = nil;
    if(dict != nil){
        [dict objectForKey:key];
        NSData *data = [dict objectForKey:key];;
        result = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
    }
    return result;
}

-(NSArray*) getDates
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self getResultsDict];
    if(dict != nil)
    {
        return [dict allKeys];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSDictionary*)getResultsDict{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *resultsDict = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"RESULTS_DICT"];
    return resultsDict;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to store the results in a dictionary, or in the defaults system? What specifically do you want to do in saveResults:forKey:?

Comment: I was looking to save the results in a dict, and put the dict in system defaults.  I've since edited my answer to include my solution.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Should really remove the answer from the question and just mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Cant do that for 2 days, I will re-edit then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, because the question seems too simple given what you've got done already...

```
-(void)saveResults:(NSArray *)scanResults  forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    self.aDictionaryProperty[key] = scanResults;
}

-(NSArray*)readResults:(NSString *) key
{
    return self.aDictionaryProperty[key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue was more so in dealing with the NSUserDefaults element, along with my cuson class.  I've since solved it and edited my answer, thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this like so:

```
 -(void)saveResults:(NSArray *)results forKey:(NSString *)key
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self getResultsDict]];
        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:results];
        if(dict == nil){
            dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:data forKey:key];
        }else{
            [dict setObject:data forKey:key];
        }

        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:dict forKey:@"RESULTS_DICT"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }

    -(NSArray*)readFullResults:(NSString *)key
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [self getResultsDict];
        NSArray *result = nil;
        if(dict != nil){
            [dict objectForKey:key];
            NSData *data = [dict objectForKey:key];;
            result = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
        }
        return result;
    }

    -(NSArray*) getDates
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [self getResultsDict];
        if(dict != nil)
        {
            return [dict allKeys];
        }
        return nil;
    }

    - (NSDictionary*)getResultsDict{
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSMutableDictionary *resultsDict = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"RESULTS_DICT"];
        return resultsDict;

    }
```